# xCode Jenkins build - configure server URL for use by App

Tags: xcode, jenkins

I am looking to configure a jenkins job, to build iOS apps, but I want to build 3 different apps for dev, staging and prod. What is the best approach you guys have taken for this kind of build jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not simple to do this well, depending on the level of complexity you need. Also it takes a reasonably good understanding of certs, provisioning profiles, Xcode build settings, and your choice of a CI server. Here's the full setup we've used.

**Method - Using configs**

If you don't need more than Debug/Release/Distribution configs, then use those.  Add a User-Defined build setting and reference it in your app's info.plist and access the plist from your app as needed. See below for the same method:

**Method - Build-Time properties**

The kind of variation you're looking for is best specified at build time.  To do this for Xcode:

1. Add a user-defined property to your build settings.
   [image]
2. Add a reference to this in your app's info.plist.  You can interpolate your build settings into your Info.plist! This is an example of setting the Display Name but you could use this for anything. That it's accessible easily from your app's code is nice too (it's where most 3rd party services have you define API keys, etc. anyway).
   [image]
3. Define a build-time env var.  Here I'm using the Xcode plugin for Jenkins to specify it but you could pass it in through CLI or however you're doing your CI builds.
   [image]

At this point you can pretty much change anything in your info.plist with a build-time argument.  Time to use it!

**Simple version - bundle ID and names**

If you just have one app with different parameters, you could just use the above information and payload that configuration in with 3 different builds with 3 different parameters.

If you want to have the different apps be installed simultaneously, then specify the product name and bundle id (like com.your.company.{$CUSTOM_BUNDLE_ID}) differently.  *This will work as long as you're using a wildcard AppID like com.your.company.* *.

**Certs, certs, more certs**

If you're using extensions or APNS or anything else that requires an explicit AppID (no wildcard), then your life is a bit harder if you want multiple simultaneous app installs.  You will essentially have to generate 3 certs/provisioning profiles for the 3 different IDs and specify them when code signing.

It's annoying but it's mostly a one-time cost and there are situations where this is useful.

**Is that it?**

Again, if you're working with a wildcard cert, mostly yes.  If you're not, then you'll have to tune other parameters as well including (but probably not limited to):
 - Different entitlements need to be specified depending on the build configuration
 - Setting up references to these names in your extensions (WatchKit, for example)
 - ??? 0_o ???

**What we did**

Our app has a blend of all of the above requirements:

- Multiple simultaneous versions of a particular app (internal, for
  example). We use the CUSTOM_PRODUCT_NAME to allow user to distinguish
  v2.5 and v2.6, for example.  Within a particular environment the apps
  will override each other.
- Multiple simultaneous environments for a
  particular app.  We actually use an enterprise distro profile for
  internal distribution as well as testing. For dev we use the standard
  dev cert. For prod we use a non-enterprise prod cert.
- Entitlements/extensions properties are also customized based upon
  build configuration.  For example, "Release" for us always uses the
  enterprise set of certs/properties.
- As we allow our apps to go cross
  environment, we also have a custom view controller invoked by a
  hidden gesture that allows our users to point a particular front end
  client (dev, staging, prod) against any other backend (dev, staging,
  prod).

It might seem complex but it serves us very well and most of it is, again, setup cost. There are a few moving parts here. Not the easiest to fully lay out in an SO post so feel free to ask for clarifications based upon your need.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to provide a functionality in the app itself to choose between the different environments. Based on what environment you choose the config settings are changed in the app.

Answer (score 0):

We use the multiple SCM option so that we can clone/checkout from two repositories.  We store configuration values for different environments in separate branches.

Even though it "feels" a bit wrong, it works well for us and we get the benefit of restricting permissions for different developers and keeping the configuration change history.

EDIT: Multiple SCM option comes from this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin